# SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) with WebRTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, video-streaming, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I am creating a group video call application using WebRTC. Currently I am using MESH architecture. Creating peer connection as below -

```
var peer_connection = new RTCPeerConnection(
    {"iceServers": ICE_SERVERS},
    {"optional": [{"DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement": true}]}
);
```

I want to use SFU with WebRTC. Can anyone please tell how to do same or share any documentation regarding same. What changes would be required in code for creating SFU based connection?

Comment: If the answer solved your problem you can mark it as solved

Answer (score 4):

An SFU is very different. It passes all the data through a central server which redirects them to every consumer. Here is an [example project](https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms) where a room based SFU is implemented using [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/)